# Creating array of arrays with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code, which when run gives error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
[Here you can run it.](http://repl.it/7Zf)

```
var myData = "some1,some2,some3\nsome4,some5,some6\nsome7,some8,some9";
var arrayed = myData.split('\n');
var columns = arrayed.length;
var urlArray = new Array(columns);
console.log(arrayed);
var newarrayed = arrayed.split(',');
console.log(newarrayed);
```

I have `myData` array, I want to convert it to an array of arrays, splitting first at `\n` to seperate arrays, and second at `,` to create the items inside the arrays. so this list would be like:

[[data1, data2, data3], [data4, data5, data6], [data7, data8, data9]]

`console.log(arrayed);` does something similar, but when I try to access it using `arrayed[0][0]`, it gives me just the first letter.

Comment: What error?  Please include all pertinent information in your question

Comment: Stack offers runnable snippets now, you should use that instead of that weird fiddle like website

Comment: Also consider cleaning up your code samples before posting them; we don't need those random commented-out bits at the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not splitting the strings correctly.  You try to split them twice, but the second time fails because you are calling `split` on an array, not a string.  Try looping over them instead.

```
var myData = "some1,some2,some3\nsome4,some5,some6\nsome7,some8,some9";
var arrayed = myData.split('\n');
var columns = arrayed.length;
var urlArray = new Array(columns);
console.log(arrayed);
var newarrayed = [];
for (var i in arrayed) {
    newarrayed.push(arrayed[i].split(','));
}
console.log(newarrayed);
```

Comment: @Ugur You're welcome.  Glad I could help. :)  The `push` command just "pushes" another value onto the end of an array.  You can also `pop` the value off again. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push